# Collection view is loading only on page load in IOS

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview

I am using Collection View for showing multiple images in a slider selected by user but the main issue is that the collection view is loading only on page load. while my array which contains images is made after the page load. That is why images are not loaded because collection view is not loaded once the page is load.
I don't know much about Collection View So kindly guide me...
My Code is below:-

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
 {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   _imageList= [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];

for (NSDictionary *dict in info)
{
   UIImage *image  = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [_imageList addObject:image];

}

self.chosenImages = _imageList;
```

}

```
- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


  -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

   return 1;
  }

 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:  (NSInteger)section{

    int numberOfItem = 0;
     if (_imageList)
     {

       numberOfItem = _imageList.count;
      }
   return numberOfItem;
 }

 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    [collectionView registerClass:[ImageCell class]   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    ImageCell *cell = (ImageCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                                           forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //    if(LOGS_ON) NSLog(@"cell = %@",cell);
      if (!cell) {

    //        if(LOGS_ON) NSLog(@"Creating cell");
    cell          = [[ImageCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 85, 110)];
    cell.delegate = self;
   }
   cell.delegate  = self;
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;

  //    if(LOGS_ON) NSLog(@"image = %@", cell.imageView);

    cell.cellImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
    }


   -(void) imageCell:(ImageCell *)imageCell buttonClickedAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [_imageList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [_imageGrid reloadData];
   }
```

_imageList in collection view number of items is not loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading imageList , reload the collection view

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
 {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   _imageList= [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];

for (NSDictionary *dict in info)
{
   UIImage *image  = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [_imageList addObject:image];

}

self.chosenImages = _imageList;
```

**// reload collection view**

```
[collectionview reloadData];

}
```